# Set dropdown option to active in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Hi all I am trying to set the value of a dropdown to `selected` when the user goes to an `edit` page of my application but currently I am getting an error and I realise it is because I do not have the correct syntax.

This is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label>Category</label>
            <select name="category_id" id="cat_drop">
                @foreach($cats as $cat)
                    <option value="{{$cat->id}} {{if($tip->category_id == $cat_id){ echo 'selected';} }}">{{$cat->name}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
```

Basically `Tips` have a `category_id` and the dropdown allows a user to change the tip category. However I would like for the currently selected category_id to be set as the value of dropdown.

I am new to `Laravel` and the `Blade` Templating engine so would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a ternary if:

```
@foreach($cats as $cat)
    <option value="{{$cat->id}}" {{($tip->category_id == $cat_id) ? 'selected':''}}>{{$cat->name}}</option>
@endforeach
```